# In matlab how to use if loop having condition (a is a scalar number and is equal to any element in a vector v of n length)

Tags: matlab

I have a function `replace_me` which is defined like as: `function w = replace_me(v,a,b,c).` The first input argument v is a vector, while a, b, and c are all scalars. The function replaces every element of v that is equal to a with b and c. For example, the command
`x = replace_me([1 2 3],2,4,5);` returns x as `[1 4 5 3]`.

The code that I have created is

```
function w = replace_me(v,a,b,c)
[row,column]=size(v);
new_col=column+1;
w=(row:new_col);
    for n=(1:column)
        if a==v(n)
            v(n)=b;
            o=n;
            d=n-1;
            u=n+1;
            for z=1:d
                w(z)=v(z);
            end
            for z=u:column
                w(z+1)=v(z);
            end
            w(o)=b;
            w(o+1)=c;
        end
    end
end
```

It works perfectly fine for `x = replace_me([1 2 3],2,4,5);` I get required output but when I try `x = replace_me([1 2 3], 4, 4, 5)` my function fails.

To resolve this problem I want to use an `if else` statements having conditions that if `a` is equal to any element of vector `v` we would follow the above equation else it returns back the vector.

I tried to use this as if condition but it didn't worked

```
if v(1:column)==a
```

Any ideas

Comment: please clarify what you are trying to do, and add some punctuation. there is no such thing as an "if loop"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve, but form what I understand you're looking for something like this:

```
function [v] = replace_me(v,a,b,c)

  v = reshape(v,numel(v),1); % Ensure that v is always a column vector
  tol = 0.001;
  aPos = find( abs(v-a) < tol ); % Used tol to avoid numerical issues as mentioned by excaza

  for i=numel(aPos):-1:1 % Loop backwards since the indices change when inserting elements
    index = aPos(i);
    v = [v(1:index-1); b; c; v(index+1:end)];
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function w = move_me(v,a)
 if nargin == 2
   w=v(v~=a);
   w(end+1:end+(length(v)-length(w)))=a;
elseif isscalar(v)
   w=v;
else
   w=v(v~=0);
   w(end+1)=0;
```

end
end

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.